# Upload bank reconciliation file to Microsoft Dynamics GP

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I need to upload a file ( bank reconciliation files ) to Microsoft Dynamics GP using C#. Can someone please help me understanding the steps to upload file to Microsoft Dynamics GP via **C#** ?

Are there any APIs available from Microsoft Dynamics GP that I can use in C# to upload a file from local drive or any SDK?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you mean by uploading file, can you give some example? Dynamics GP is an ERP and it's various forms/windows allow to save attachments with different document types like item, customer, sales Order, purchase order etc.

Comment: I need to upload bank reconciliation files to dynamics GP. 
For that I was looking for APIs that I can use to upload files via C#